# Local HTTP Request not sending with Axios on React Native Expo app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, http, axios, expo

I am writing a react native expo app that utilizes a .NET backend that I've already established and has worked quite well for a while. Recently, I've gotten to the point of attempting local http requests with axios for my mobile app rather than mock data, and it worked wonderfully for a bit. I have a few get requests that are called in a useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getAll() {
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `${baseUrl}/ItemName`,
            headers: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));

        if(response?.data) {
            setItemName(response.data);
        }
    }

    getAll();
}, []);
```

Then after that was working, I wanted to put in authentication within the app itself rather than using the backend Swagger and copying the token every 30 minutes. Made a signup page and the form worked just fine, but when I made the new axios post request, none of the requests worked - even those that were working before hand. The post looks like this:

```
    const postNewUser = async (values) => {
        try {
            const postObject = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: `${baseUrl}/User/Register`,
                data: {
                    firstName: values.firstName,
                    lastName: values.lastName,
                    username: values.username,
                    password: values.password,
                    email: values.email,
                    phoneNumber: values.phone,
                    birthDate: moment(values.birthDate).toISOString()
                },
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            };

            const response = await axios(postObject);

            if(response) {
                navigation.navigate('Login', {
                    desiredUsername: values.username
                });
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        }
    }
```

I've been googling for over a week now trying different answers multiple different times. I've tried updating my nodejs, tried different versions of axios, tried different baseUrls for the request (localhost, 10.0.2.2, and my personal IP) but none of them work. Strangely, localhost and my IP both return very quickly, and 10.0.2.2 takes a solid 30 seconds but returns the same error message.

I have put a log into the user controller on my backend to show whether or not I'm actually hitting the backend or not, and with postman or swagger I get there just fine. With the mobile axios call I don't hit that log, so I'm not even getting to the backend at all. Instead I'm getting a not-so-useful error as follows:

```
Stack: AxiosError@http://personalIP:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:114554:29
    handleTimeout@http://personalIP:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:115572:39
    dispatchEvent@http://personalIP:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:30065:31
    setReadyState@http://personalIP:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:28693:33
    __didCompleteResponse@http://personalIP:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:28499:29
    emit@http://personalIP:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:2310:40
    __callFunction@http://personalIP:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21321:36
    @http://personalIP:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21071:31
    __guard@http://personalIP:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21269:15
    callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://personalIP:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21070:21
    callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]

Message: timeout exceeded
Name: AxiosError
Code: ECONNABORTED
Config: {
    "adapter": [
        "xhr",
        "http"
    ],
    "data": "{\"firstName\":\"Test\",\"lastName\":\"Test\",\"username\":\"test\",\"password\":\"P@ssw0rd\",\"email\":\"email@example.com\",\"phoneNumber\":\"5555555555\",\"birthDate\":\"2022-11-27T19:13:57.458Z\"}",
    "env": {
        "Blob": [Function Blob
        ],
        "FormData": [Function FormData
        ]
    },
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "method": "post",
    "timeout": 0,
    "transformRequest": [
        [Function transformRequest
        ]
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
        [Function transformResponse
        ]
    ],
    "transitional": {
        "clarifyTimeoutError": false,
        "forcedJSONParsing": true,
        "silentJSONParsing": true
    },
    "url": "http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/User/Register",
    "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus
    ],
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
}
    Request: {
    "DONE": 4,
    "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
    "LOADING": 3,
    "OPENED": 1,
    "UNSENT": 0,
    "_aborted": false,
    "_cachedResponse": undefined,
    "_hasError": true,
    "_headers": {
        "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "_incrementalEvents": false,
    "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {},
    "_method": "POST",
    "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/User/Register",
    "_performanceLogger": {
        "_closed": false,
        "_extras": {},
        "_pointExtras": {},
        "_points": {
            "initializeCore_end": 606677771.370125,
            "initializeCore_start": 606677745.343875
        },
        "_timespans": {
            "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/User/Register": [Object
            ],
            "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://personalIp:19000/logs": [Object
            ],
            "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://personalIp:19000/symbolicate": [Object
            ],
            "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://personalIp:5000/api/User/Register": [Object
            ],
            "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://localhost:5000/api/User/Register": [Object
            ]
        }
    },
    "_requestId": null,
    "_response": "The request timed out.",
    "_responseType": "",
    "_sent": true,
    "_subscriptions": [],
    "_timedOut": true,
    "_trackingName": "unknown",
    "_url": "http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/User/Register",
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseHeaders": undefined,
    "status": 0,
    "timeout": 0,
    "upload": {},
    "withCredentials": true
}
```

I'm testing this currently on my mobile expo app. I've tested in the past on the web version but SecureStore doesn't work with web. I was able to confirm before adding the new requests that the mobile version was able to call the getAll just fine before the signup was added.

Comment: Localhost won't work because it will point to the device, is the local api accessible  from a different machine on the network which the device is connected

Comment: @Azzy not sure how I'd figure that out. The backend and front end are running on the same machine, then using my phone to figure that out. I'm not great at anything network, so not sure how to answer your question properly. Thanks

Comment: If there is an unauthenticated get api, try opening it from a browser of the device or emulator, then call the same api thru the app,  that way we can narrow down to the actual issue

Comment: Is it possible to make a call to a [public test api](https://swapi.py4e.com/api/planets/1/?format=wookiee) like starwars api

Comment: @Azzy I switched out for the star wars call and that worked. Trying to hit from my phone's browser does not get me anything back. I presume this means it is somehow my backend even though it's not ever being hit?

Comment: Yep, the phone browser should be able to access an unauthenticated get api, you can also try to make call through [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) from another machine on the network, Hope you are able to sort it out